Change description of value inside an array in Dymola
I created a simple array in Dymola 2022
parameter Modelica.Units.SI.AbsolutePressure Pa_0[5]={30,30,30,30,30};

And when I am using it, its description inside the variable browser is not set.

If I add a description when I declare the array
parameter Modelica.Units.SI.AbsolutePressure Pa_0[5]={30,30,30,30,30} "Test";

The description change for all the value of the array.
Does anyone know how to individually change the description value of each values of the array?
Thanks for your help

EDIT :
In the example above I used a parameter, the final purpose is to apply it to a signal sized as a vector, or even to larger array

Using a record parameter might the prefered parameterization then.

thanks for you answer.
Do you mean, that I should:

in a record, declare each term of my array with their description
then use this record in my connector to pass the description to all the value which will be used in the signal of the connector?

Something like:
record Pa_record
Modelica.Units.SI.AbsolutePressure a "1st description";
Modelica.Units.SI.AbsolutePressure b "2nd description";
end record Pa_record;
connector Pa_connector
input Pa_record Pa;
end connector Pa_connector;

I also wonder if the description change if later we have something like :
Pa[2] = C;
with C written as,
Real C = 5 "3rd description";
In this case, if the 2nd description would be overwritten by 3rd description. ==> let's try

Regarding the original question: From what I know it is not possible to adapt the description of elements of an array in Modelica.

Regarding the last comment: The description of the parameter will not change if other values are assigned to it.

Another option I found (but which less complete the need) is :
Define the record :
record P_r
  Modelica.Units.SI.AbsolutePressure Pa "1st description";
end P_r;

Define the connector with the record as a vector :
connector Connect_P_r
   output P_r P[3];
end Connect_P_r;

Create a model to test :
model Source_P_r
  Connect_P_r c_P_r ;
equation 
  c_P_r.P[1].Pa = 10;
  c_P_r.P[2].Pa = 20;
  c_P_r.P[3].Pa = 30;
end Source_P_r;

As seeable on the picture I have the description available. But I was not able to find the way to individualy change the description (I mean to have a different description between P1 and P[2] ...)
If you know how to do that, it will helps to solve the problem


For now the best I can get is :
Define a record :
record P_record
  Modelica.Units.SI.AbsolutePressure Pa "1st description";
  Modelica.Units.SI.AbsolutePressure Pb "2nd description";
  Modelica.Units.SI.AbsolutePressure Pab[2] = {Pa, Pb};
end P_record;

Use it (for example in a connector):
connector Connect_P
   output P_record P;
end Connect_P;

Create a model to test :
model Source_P_record
  parameter P_record P_0r = P_record(10, 20); //It fills automaticaly Pab
  Connect_P connect_P1;
equation 
  connect_P1.P.Pab = P_0r.Pab; // It deduces Pa and Pb
end Source_P_record;

Based on that, it is possible to use Pab as a vector for any problem (ex: for loop), Pa and Pb will be computed from Pab.
And so to use Pa and Pb in the Variable browser (in which I have the description of Pa and Pb and unfortunatelynot in Pab) to plot the results.

